# Why ripgrep results from python subprocess run differ from rg run in the shell

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, ripgrep

If I run `rg` in bash directly, the output information includes the found file names (on a separate line), and then on a separate line for each match the line number and content for that match:

```
11:38 (main *+) durl $ rg format
durl/__main__.py
35:            print(util.format_output(repo.url, line))
38:            print(util.format_output(repo.url, line, linenumber=n))

durl/util.py
15:def format_output(prefix, filename: str, linenumber: str=None) -> str:
```

But if I run the same command from python `subprocess` run, the displayed information of the matched results includes the filename on each line and *do not* include a line number. Why is that so? (I am running on MacOS)

```
11:38 (main *+) durl $ ipython
Python 3.9.5 (default, May  4 2021, 03:36:27)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.27.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import subprocess

In [2]: p = subprocess.run('rg format', text=True, shell=True, capture_output=True,)

In [3]: p.stdout
Out[3]: 'durl/__main__.py:            print(util.format_output(repo.url, line))\ndurl/__main__.py:            print(util.format_output(repo.url, line, linenumber=n))\ndurl/util.py:def format_output(prefix, filename: str, linenumber: str=None) -> str:\n'

In [4]: p.stdout.split('\n')
Out[4]:
['durl/__main__.py:            print(util.format_output(repo.url, line))',
 'durl/__main__.py:            print(util.format_output(repo.url, line, linenumber=n))',
 'durl/util.py:def format_output(prefix, filename: str, linenumber: str=None) -> str:',
 '']
```

Comment: Try `rg format | cat` in your shell and compare to `rg format` alone.

Comment: (Also, please don't make it readers' problems to try to figure out what the specific difference you're asking about is; it's not as visually obvious as you may think that the filenames are only reproduced on each line in the stdout-to-a-FIFO case; I had to reread several times to catch it, and one answerer apparently missed it entirely -- have now edited to be more explicit).

Comment: BTW, if you dropped the `capture_output=True`, you'd have the same behavior for both (because `rg` would inherit stdout from Python and thus see that output was going to a TTY, and thus optimize for human-friendly behavior as opposed to machine-friendly behavior).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because ripgrep detects if an interactive tty exists on stdout, and if so, changes the output format to be more "friendly." It's the same thing that `ls` does for example.